# use discriminator column in edm

Tags: entity-framework

I have employee as a base class with salaried and hourly employees as derived classes, using employee_type as the discriminator. Is there anyway to keep the employee_type in the model. I need to use it in subsequent quires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

You can refer to it indirectly, though.

```
var q = from e in Employees
        let eType = e is Hourly ? "Hourly" : "Salaried"
        select ...
```

Having said that, this is a questionable design. An hourly employee can never become salaried, because objects can't change type! What if I'm promoted?